# Does a '%' in a pattern match an empty string?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html#Selective-Search):***

> A `vpath` pattern is a string containing a `%` character.  The string
>   must match the file name of a prerequisite that is being searched for,
>   the `%` character matching any sequence of zero or more characters (as
>   in pattern rules).

Now, although, it is true that `%` does match an ***empty*** string (string of zero length) in a vpath pattern (`vpath % foo`), this is not true for pattern-rules.

So, it is ***wrong*** for the documentation above, to equate between them, as:

> ...the '%' character matching any sequence of zero or more characters (as
>   in pattern rules.

***As this is simply not true, as evident by the following Makefile:***

```make
all ::

al%l :
    @echo '$@'
```

.

***Executing, we get:***

```console
# It is evident that 'all' doesn't match 'al%l'
$ make -r
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

# But, 'all' does match 'al%'
$ make  -r -f makefile -f <(echo 'al% : ; echo $@')
echo all
all
```

.

***In fact, this is well [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro):***

> For example, `%.c` as a pattern matches any file name that ends in
>   `.c`.  `s.%.c` as a pattern matches any file name that starts with `s.`,
>   ends in `.c` and is at least five characters long.  (There must be at
>   least one character to match the `%`.)  The substring that the `%`
>   matches is called the "stem".

Agree?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

The problem in your example is that you are mixing and matching single vs. double colon recipes. This is explicitly not allowed, you need to do one or the other for all matching rules.

Also, having different patterns does not qualify as being the same target and the most specific match will usually get run and the others ignored (even if a zero width match as in your example might be present).